# unable to print out list objects in different cases in a switch statement

Tags: c#

I am making an interface to store character and dinosaur variables to a list and then print them out when asked.

There is a switch statement to take the users' inputs:

- Case 1: The function allows the user to input character data and then it's put into a list.
- Case 2.: The function allows the user to input dinosaur
  data and then it put into a list.
- Case 3 The function prints the objects in each list. However, whenever I run it it doesn't print anything and comes up with no errors. If I run the code to print each list in their respective case then they print out fine.

```
    class Program
    {
        
        static void Main()
        {
            
            int NumAns;
            Console.WriteLine("*1. Character Creator     ");
            Console.WriteLine("*2. Dinosaur Creator      ");
            Console.WriteLine("*3. Display               "); 
            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine("Specify your menu choice");
            string NumAnsString = Console.ReadLine();
            NumAns = Convert.ToInt32(NumAnsString);
            MenuChosen(NumAns);
            
        }

        static void MenuChosen(int selection)
        {
            
            List<Dinosaur> Dinosaur_l = new List<Dinosaur>();
            List<Character> CharSave = new List<Character>();
            Character character = new Character();
            Dinosaur dinosaur = new Dinosaur();
            switch (selection)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("You chose Character Creator");
                    character.CharacterVal();
                    CharSave.Add(new Character
                    {
                        name = character.name,
                        age = character.age,
                        height = character.height,
                        hair = character.hair,
                        eyes = character.eyes,
                        glasses = character.glasses
                    });
                    Main();
                    break;


                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("You chose Dinosaurs");
                    dinosaur.DinoVal();
                    Dinosaur_l.Add(new Dinosaur
                    {
                        name = dinosaur.name,
                        species = dinosaur.species,
                        diet = dinosaur.diet,
                        sex = dinosaur.sex
                    }); 
                    
                    Main();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    Console.WriteLine("Character: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    foreach (Character chara in CharSave)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(chara.name);
                        Console.WriteLine(chara.age);
                        Console.WriteLine(chara.height);
                        Console.WriteLine(chara.hair);
                        Console.WriteLine(chara.eyes);
                        Console.WriteLine(chara.glasses);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    Console.WriteLine("Dinosaurs: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");

                    foreach (Dinosaur Dino in Dinosaur_l)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(Dino.name);
                        Console.WriteLine(Dino.species);
                        Console.WriteLine(Dino.diet);
                        Console.WriteLine(Dino.sex);


                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    Main();
                    break;
            }


        }
    }
```

This is the code used for CharacterVal function

```
public class Character
    {
         public string name;
         public string age;
         public string height;
         public string hair;
         public string eyes;
         public string glasses;
         public int charID = 0;
         int x = 1;

        public void CharacterVal()
        {
            charID++;
            Console.WriteLine("Name your Character: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("How old is " + name + "? :");
            age = Console.ReadLine();
            

            Console.WriteLine("How tall is " + name + "?: ");
            height = Console.ReadLine();
          

            Console.WriteLine("What colour is " + name + "'s hair ?: ");
            hair = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What colour is " + name + "'s eyes ?: ");
            eyes = Console.ReadLine();

            GlassesCheck();

        }

        public void GlassesCheck()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("does " + name + " wear glasses? (yes/no): ");
            while (x == 1)
            {
                glasses = Console.ReadLine();
                if(glasses =="yes")
                {
                    x = 2;
                }
                else if(glasses == "no")
                {
                    x = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    x = 1;
                   Console.WriteLine("'"+glasses+"' is not a valid answer, does " + name + " wear glasses? (yes/no): "); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code used for the DinoVal function

```
public class Dinosaur
    {
        public string species;
        public string diet;
        public string sex;
        public string name;
        public void DinoVal()
        {
            
                Console.WriteLine("***************************");
                Console.WriteLine("*Choose a Dinosaur        *");
                Console.WriteLine("*                         *");
                Console.WriteLine("*1. Alvarezsaurus         *");
                Console.WriteLine("*2. Avimimus              *");
                Console.WriteLine("*3. Bactrosaurus          *");
                Console.WriteLine("*4. Baryonyx              *");
                Console.WriteLine("*5. Coloradisaurus        *");
                Console.WriteLine("*6. Chungkingosaurus      *");
                Console.WriteLine("***************************");
                int Selection = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (Selection)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("you have chosen the Alvarezsaurus");
                        Console.WriteLine("This is a Carnivore ");
                        species = "Alvarezsaurus";
                        diet = "Carnivore";
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("you have chosen the Avimimus");
                        Console.WriteLine("This is an Omnivore  ");
                        species = "Avimimus";
                        diet = "Omnivore";
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("you have chosen the Bactrosaurus");
                        Console.WriteLine("This is a Herbivore ");
                        species = "Bactrosaurus";
                        diet = "Herbivore";
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        Console.WriteLine("you have chosen the Baryonyx");
                        Console.WriteLine("This is a Carnivore ");
                        species = "Baryonyx";
                        diet = "Carnivore";
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("you have chosen the Coloradisaurus");
                        Console.WriteLine("This is an Omnivore ");
                        species = "Coloradisaurus";
                        diet = "Omnivore";
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        Console.WriteLine("you have chosen the Chungkingosaurus");
                        Console.WriteLine("This is a Herbivore ");
                        species = "Chungkingosaurus";
                        diet = "Herbivore";
                        break;

                }
                
                
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose the dinosaurs sex");
                Console.WriteLine("1.Male");
                Console.WriteLine("2.Female");
                int GenderChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (GenderChoice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("the dinosaur will be male");
                        sex = "Male";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("the dinosaur will be female");
                        sex = "Female";
                        break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("What name will you give this " + sex + " " + species + " ?:");
                name = Console.ReadLine();                            
        }
    }
```

i've tried moving

```
CharSave.Add(new Character
                    {
                        name = character.name,
                        age = character.age,
                        height = character.height,
                        hair = character.hair,
                        eyes = character.eyes,
                        glasses = character.glasses
                    });
```

into case 3 but all that does is print blank spaces for each object

Comment: Please check my [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71632998/revisions). I was not sure if the part starting with "however" refers to part 3 or is more general. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lists that store the characters and the dinos need to be outside of the `MenuChosen` method because as you code is written everytime `MenuChosen` is called new lists are created.

You could:

```
class Program
{
    static List<Dinosaur> Dinosaur_l = new List<Dinosaur>();
    static List<Character> CharSave = new List<Character>();
}
```

## Main -> MenuChosen -> Main -> MenuChosen -> ...

Because the way you structured (Main calls MenuChosen which calls Main and so on) your code - if you run the game for long enough - will get end up with a stack overflow.

To avoid this you can run your code in a loop:

```
Main()
{
    while (true) // or selection was 'Quit', etc. 
    {
      your code here 
    }

// Remove calls to 'Main' from the switch statement.
```